# Confusion In AppBilling v3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing App Billing V3 in My Android app.I have a  little confusion in implementation.In Android Developer Website implementation describe with two type.

1st [First Implementation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

2nd [Second Implementation](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html)

Problem is  which i should use.& what the diffrence b/w each other.

Comment: Should describe the same thing, have you found any actual differences?

Comment: ya i have found that in Second implemention it describe how connection is established & in first all the connection initiate by ServiceConnection.

Comment: Maybe one is simply referring to the sample app and helper classes, while the other is more general?

Comment: hmm may be  thanks nikolay nice to talk with u